An Extension to a Floor Equation Problem from MPFG
A friend asked me this problem:
Determine the number of real solutions $x$ to the equation $x^2+\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + 2x$, where $1\leq x\leq 20$.
I solved it by observing that all $x$'s that make $(x-1)^2$ integral suffice. More precisely, observe that $(x-1)^2 = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor - \lfloor 2x \rfloor + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so the number of solutions $c$ is at most $362$ given that $1\leq x \leq 20$. In fact, we argue that the number of solutions is precisely $362$. Suppose $(x-1)^2=k$ is a positive integer. Then $x= 1+ \sqrt{k}$ given that $x\geq 1$. Now notice that the original equation could be simplified as $\{x^2\}=\{2x\}$. Plugging in $x=1+\sqrt{k}$, we observe that $\text{LHS}=\{2\sqrt{k}\}=\text{RHS}$. Therefore, $x$ is a solution to the equation as long as $(x-1)^2$ is an integer. (q.e.d.)
Along the way I also made this interesting observation: The number of solutions ${C}(n)$ to $x^2+\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + 2x$ in the interval $\left[\frac{1}{2}n, \frac{1}{2}(n+1)\right)$ is given by the following recursion:
${C}(n) = {C}(n-1)+ \frac{1}{2}(1+3\cdot (-1)^n)$. Note that although this observation might not be particularly useful in solving this problem, some interesting implications about solving more general frac functions equating quadratics to linears, i.e., $\{ax+b\}=\{cx^2\}$ do entail.
I guess proving the conjecture given above would be a nice first step.

I figured it out! Here's my proof:
We want to show that
The number of integer solutions $k$ to $1+\sqrt{k} \in \left[ \frac{1}{2}n, \frac{1}{2}(n+1)\right)$, denoted $C(n)$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\geq 2$ is given by the recursion $C(n)=C(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}(1+3(-1)^n).$
First, it is easy to show that our claim is equivalent to
$$C(n) = \begin{cases} \frac{n}{2}, & n \text{ even}, \\
                   \frac{n-3}{2}, & n \text{ odd}. \end{cases}$$
Now suppose $n$ is odd. Suppose $C(n)$ counts the set $S=\{a_n, a_n+1, \ldots, a_n+C(n)-1\}$. We would like to show that elements in the set $\{a_n+C(n), a_n+C(n)+1, \ldots, a_n+2C(n)+1\}$ are bounded above by $\frac{1}{4}n^2$. We could do so by proving that
$$a_n+2C(n)+1=a_n+n-2<\frac{1}{4}n^2$$.
For the sake of contradiction suppose that $a_n \geq \frac{1}{4}n^2-n+2$. Then $a_n-1$ satisfies the inequality $\frac{1}{2}n-1\leq \sqrt{a_n-1}$, so $a_n-1$ should also be a solution to $\frac{1}{2}n\leq 1+\sqrt{k}<\frac{1}{2}(n+1)$, which is impossible given that it does not belong to $S$. Next we also need to verify that $a_n+n-1 \geq \frac{1}{4}n^2$. This is true given that $\sqrt{a_n} \geq \frac{1}{2}n-1$.
Next, if $n$ is even, define $S$, the set of solutions $k$ to $1+\sqrt{k} \in \left[ \frac{1}{2}n, \frac{1}{2}(n+1)\right)$ analogously. Note that by the general formula we derived, the proof follows identically.
